# Linear regression function vectorization

Tags: r, performance, vectorization, linear-regression

I want to write a script for running regression models across a whole data.table, where my function fits the model and extracts information for later analysis. I have a very large number of models to fit, so I want to make this fast. I want to vectorize this function in order to do this, but have struggled as there are NA values interspersed across the data and I do not want to impute missing values, just fit each model with the data available. I also want to extract a few statistics from the model. So my question is, can this function be vectorized and if so how?

In summary, the aim is to fit a simple linear regression model of the "dependent_var" (first column) versus each of predictor columns (in isolation) using the "covariate" column as a covariate (last column). So from each model, I want the following:

```
return(indepent_var = col, 
       pearson = cor_coef, 
       pearson_p = p_value, 
       indepent_var_beta = slope, 
       indepent_var_beta_sig = slope_sig,
       adj_r_squared = adj_r_squared, 
       indepent_var_beta_se = se_slope, 
       intercept_se = se_intercept, 
       n_obs = nrow(dfx_subset)) # dfx subset being the subset used to fit the model in question.
```

## Toy data

As an example dataset

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
num_rows <- 300
num_cols <- 6000
# Random data
data <- matrix(rnorm(num_rows * num_cols), nrow = num_rows)
# Many columns include NAs which need to be handled during fit without imputation
prop_na <- runif(num_cols, min = 0.1, max = 0.5)
for (i in 1:num_cols) {
  num_na <- round(prop_na[i] * num_rows)
  idx_na <- sample(1:num_rows, num_na)
  data[idx_na, i] <- NA
}
# Mock table, dependent variable and binary covariate variable
DT <- as.data.table(cbind(data, covariate = sample(0:1, num_rows, replace = TRUE)))
setnames(DT, old = c("V1"), new = c("dependent_var"))
```

I may include more covariates in the future, so would like to include Pearson coefficients for some quick checks/potential future analyses. As I have a lot of data to process I'd ideally just submit this once on the HPC. Here is my function so far:

## Linear regression function

```
lm_analysis <- function(col, dfx) {
  tryCatch({
    dfx_subset <- dfx[complete.cases(dfx[[1]], dfx[[col]], dfx[["covariate"]]), ]
    ## Compute Pearson correlation
    cor_test <- cor.test(dfx_subset[[1]], dfx_subset[[col]])
    cor_coef <- cor_test$estimate
    p_value <- cor_test$p.value
    ## Linear regression
    lm_result <- lm(dfx_subset[[1]] ~ dfx_subset[[col]] + dfx_subset[["covariate"]], data = dfx_subset)
    slope <- lm_result$coefficients[2]
    model_summary <- summary(lm_result)
    slope_sig <- model_summary$coefficients[2, 4]
    adj_r_squared <- model_summary$adj.r.squared
    se_slope <- model_summary$coefficients[2, "Std. Error"]
    se_intercept <- model_summary$coefficients[1, "Std. Error"]
    
    return(c(indepent_var = col, 
             pearson = cor_coef, 
             pearson_p = p_value, 
             indepent_var_beta = slope, 
             indepent_var_beta_sig = slope_sig,
             adj_r_squared = adj_r_squared, 
             indepent_var_beta_se = se_slope, 
             intercept_se = se_intercept, 
             n_obs = nrow(dfx_subset)))
  }, error = function(e){
    return(NULL)
  })
}
```

## Function application:

```
predictor_cols <- setdiff(names(DT), c("dependent_var", "covariate"))

lm_results <- lapply(predictor_cols, lm_analysis, dfx = DT)

results_lmfit <- as.data.table(do.call(rbind, lm_results))
```

I do not want to filter any observations before the analysis. Also ideally I do not want to parallelise this component as I plan to do this on the outer loop, where I will be performing the above operation on a data.table of dependent variables.

I am at a loose end in terms of how to vectorize this, and due to the mismatching data between different datasets I wasn't sure if this could easily be achievable. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you didn't have the incommensurate `NA` values you could easily do the whole thing by using a matrix as the response. Without that I don't think it's going to be possible to truly vectorize this.  You could certainly do it in a loop, and it might be fast enough (using various tricks like `lm.fit()`)

Comment: Could you compute the regression stats from the correlations and dispense with the lm calls?

Answer (score 2):

You could melt the dataset and apply a slightly simpler function, where the returned object is a list:

#### slightly simpler function

```
lm_analysis_simple <- function(d,i,c) {
  
    cor_test <- cor.test(d,i)
    ## Linear regression
    lm_result <- lm(d ~ i+c, model=FALSE)
    model_summary = summary(lm_result)

    return(list(
             pearson = cor_test$estimate, 
             pearson_p = cor_test$p.value, 
             indepent_var_beta = lm_result$coefficients[2], 
             indepent_var_beta_sig = model_summary$coefficients[2, 4],
             adj_r_squared = model_summary$adj.r.squared, 
             indepent_var_beta_se = model_summary$coefficients[2, "Std. Error"], 
             intercept_se = model_summary$coefficients[1, "Std. Error"],
             n_obs = length(i)
    ))
}
```

#### melt the dataset

```
DT_long = melt(DT,id.vars = c("dependent_var", "covariate"),variable.name = "independ_var")
```

#### apply the function by each independent variable

```
na.omit(DT_long)[, lm_analysis_simple(dependent_var,value,covariate),independ_var]
```

Output:

```
      independ_var     pearson  pearson_p indepent_var_beta indepent_var_beta_sig adj_r_squared indepent_var_beta_se intercept_se n_obs
            <fctr>       <num>      <num>             <num>                 <num>         <num>                <num>        <num> <int>
   1:           V2  0.01870141 0.83733080       0.006931742            0.94264543  -0.006405378           0.09614583    0.1301829   123
   2:           V3 -0.04812460 0.55734413      -0.044441539            0.54942591  -0.002966220           0.07406963    0.1113687   151
   3:           V4  0.08896426 0.27255406       0.094223500            0.23947211  -0.001749838           0.07978495    0.1087159   154
   4:           V5 -0.14207020 0.07881438      -0.152165312            0.07242134   0.010553751           0.08411006    0.1092392   154
   5:           V6 -0.01676149 0.85888333      -0.008136059            0.92309369   0.004776748           0.08408907    0.1087452   115
  ---                                                                                                                                  
5995:        V5996 -0.15043800 0.10393970      -0.133171088            0.10896949   0.005849612           0.08243966    0.1128392   118
5996:        V5997  0.01159498 0.89068030       0.009851107            0.90131503  -0.011246345           0.07930029    0.1115778   143
5997:        V5998 -0.13492708 0.16384292      -0.133010591            0.13078530   0.010763237           0.08733929    0.1177022   108
5998:        V5999 -0.10859013 0.17441982      -0.113119773            0.17429042   0.003738834           0.08288311    0.1106717   158
5999:        V6000  0.07089022 0.47237635       0.059207306            0.48172533  -0.013942846           0.08384918    0.1323993   105
```

Not a formal benchmarking analysis, but approx 10 times faster on my machine:

```
Unit: seconds
 expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
 melt  2.946706  2.983392  3.01590  2.988174  3.062205  3.194201    10
   op 29.996885 30.034163 30.21851 30.094909 30.355622 30.840868    10
```

Comment: This is useful but it's hard to tell whether it's "vectorization" in the sense requested by the OP ...

Comment: that's true @BenBolker, I just took it to mean "faster", and while my approach is about 10 times faster on the toy dataset, I agree, I didn't directly answer the OP's request for vectorization

Comment: maybe point that out in your answer ...